# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type in nodejs and solidity

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, solidity

i need set networks in my contract . i use the nodejs and type script .

i wrote this code :

```
    let networkId: any = await global.web3.eth.net.getId();
    let tetherData = await Tether.networks[networkId];
```

but it show me this error :

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{}'.ts(7053)

**now how can i solve the problem ?**

this is json file of my contract

[image]

Comment: Add `let tetherData:any` ?

Comment: @JeremyThille still have a problem

Comment: you get empty `networks` object, because migrations had not been deployed, i.e. 
`const Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations")
module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations)
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let networkId: number = await global.web3.eth.net.getId();
let tetherData = await Tether.networks[(networkId as number)];
```

**Why:**

```
getId(callback?: (error: Error, id: number) => void): Promise<number>;
                                                              ^^^^^^
```

https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/blob/ed1011438c3a7e35da8390998f6d1cb9b34db014/packages/web3-core/types/index.d.ts#L253

Comment: still show me that error

Comment: i using the `web3js` not `web3-core`

Comment: web3-core is depencency of web3js

Comment: still i have problem . my problem in this line : 

`let tetherData = await Tether.networks[networkId];`

Comment: updated answer with `as number`

Comment: no my friend . still have a problem

Comment: what is your solution ?